# Threads hierarchy design in kernel in CUDA

Tags: cuda

Assuming a block has limit of 512 threads, say my kernel needs more than 512 threads for execution, how should one design the thread hierarchy for optimal performance?
(case 1)

1st block - 512 threads
2nd block - remaining threads

(case 2) distribute equal number of threads across certain blocks.

Comment: If a kernel needs some 600 threads, will d best option be to allocate 300 threads  in 2 blocks. or is there any option to utilise all 512 threads of 1st block and remaining in 2nd block ?

Comment: I think it depends on the problem you are trying to solve.  Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: also if my kernel needs 601 threads or any odd number as such, how should one allocate the blocks ?

Comment: @KLee1, this was a generic question. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it really matters, but it is more important to group the thread blocks logically, so that you are able to use other CUDA optimizations (like memory coalescing)

[This link](http://www.greatlakesconsortium.org/events/GPUMulticore/Chapter3-CudaThreadingModel.pdf) provides some insight into how CUDA will (likely) and organize your threads.

A quote from the summary:

> To summarize, special parameters at a
>   kernel launch define the dimensions of
>   a grid and its blocks.  Unique
>   coordinates in blockId and threadId
>   variables allow threads of a grid to
>   distinguish among them.  It is the
>   programmer's responsibility to use
>   these variables in the kernel
>   functions so that the threads can
>   properly identify the portion of the
>   data to process.  These variables
>   compel the programmers to organize
>   threads and there data into
>   hierarchical and multi-dimensional
>   organizations.

Answer (score 0):

It is preferable to divide equally the threads into two blocks, in order to maximize the computation / memory access overlap. When you have for instance 256 threads in a block, they do not compute all in the same time, there are scheduled on the SM by warp of 32 threads. When a warp is waiting for a global memory data, another warp is scheduled. If you have a small block of threads, your global memory accesses are a lot more penalizing.

Furthermore, in your example you underuse your GPU. Just remember that a GPU have dozens of multiprocessors (eg. 30 for the C1060 Tesla), and a block is mapped to a multiprocessor. In your case, you will only use 2 multiprocessors.